# How did -1/√2 and 1/√2 turn into 0 and 1? and how to find the ker f?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the matrix representation A<sub>ββ</sub> of f with respect to β = {b1,b2}. The values of b1 and b2 are given to me.
b1 =  \begin{bmatrix}1/√2\\1/√2\end{bmatrix}
and b2 = \begin{bmatrix}-1/√2\\1/√2\end{bmatrix}

and here's what I got:

I have f(b1) =

\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}

and f(b2) =

\begin{bmatrix}-1/√2\\1/√2\end{bmatrix}

This means that my A<sub>ββ</sub> should be

\begin{bmatrix}0&-1/√2\\0&1/√2\end{bmatrix}

right?

but the solution says that A<sub>ββ</sub> should be

\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}

Why is that? How did -1/√2 and 1/√2 turn into 0 and 1? is it because of rref? and how do I find the kernel of f?

Comment: Is your $f(b_2)$ expressed in the $\beta$ basis?

Comment: Your matrix is similar to the given matrix, so the given matrix is the matrix of the same function but in a different basis.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it is.

Comment: Let me guess: $b_2=\pmatrix{-1/\sqrt2\\ 1/\sqrt2}$?

Comment: @Berci yes, that's right.

Comment: So, that's why. $f(b_1)=0b_1+0b_2$ while $f(b_2)=0b_1+1b_2$, right? These coefficients go in the matrix columns.

Comment: Your response to me and your response to Berci seem contradictory.

Comment: Oh yes @Berci, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, what you obtained first is $A_{\beta,\gamma}$ with $\gamma$ the standard basis.

Comment: @Arthur, oh, I understand what you mean now. Sorry, actually it wasn't expressed in the  basis earlier.

Comment: @Berci and others, is the kernel of f the zero vector? and is the image of f: α(1     -1)^T? if the question asks find the kernel of f, should I find the kernel of , with  the standard basis or  with the  basis? Thanks.

Comment: To answer this question, you need to know what $b_1$ and $b_2$ are. From the intended answer, it is possible to deduce that $b_2$ equals $\begin{pmatrix}-1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$, but that should really be part of the question. The OP knows them ('The values of b1 and b2 are given to me'), but is not giving them in this question.

Comment: @Magdiragdag   b1 = Transpose of (1/√2, 1/√2)

Comment: That information should be added to the question.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I have made the necessary edit now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $i$th column of the matrix $A_{\beta,\gamma}$ of a linear map $A:V\to W$ w.r.t bases $\beta=(b_1,b_2,\dots)$ in $V$ and $\gamma\in W$ consists of the coefficients of $A(b_i)$ when written as a linear combination of elements of $\gamma$, i.e. the $\gamma$-coordinates of $A(b_i)$.

In your case what you obtained is $A_{\beta,\gamma}$ with $\gamma$=standard basis instead of $A_{\beta,\beta}$ which was asked.

The kernel of $A$ consists of all vectors $v\in V$ for which $A(v)=0$.
In this example $\ker A$ is generated by $b_1$.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the value of b1 and b2 given. Could you please elaborate on how in this case Ker A is generated by b1?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem? Probably that's the fastest approach. Nevertheless, $b_1$ is clearly in the kernel as $f(b_1)=0$. Now, $f(\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2)=\alpha_2b_2$ it's zero iff $\alpha_2=0$...

Comment: can we just say that the kernel is  *$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\1 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, exactly. This coincides with the subspace generated by $b_1$.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how we could find the image of f in this case. How to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: Since $b_1,b_2$ is a basis, any vector can be written as $\alpha b_1+\alpha b_2$, right? Some comments ago I just summarized what $f$ does to $\alpha b_1+\alpha b_2$. Can you find the image ( = range) of $f$ based on that information?

Comment: You wrote (11+22)=22 . I suppose that would mean that the image is  *
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\
    1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

but I don't understand how you got (11+22)=22.

Comment: Omg... :) How did I get? You calculated $f(b_1)=0$ and $f(b_2)=b_2$. And we know $f$ is linear. So....

Comment: Ah, I see your point. But doesn't it rely on the assumption that f(1b1 + 2b2) = 1f(b1) + 2f(b2)? How do we assume that? And is the image value I wrote in my above comment correct? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes the image is correct. And the assumption you wrote is exactly the property of being *linear*. If a map is not linear, it makes no (or much less) sense to write up 'its matrix'. The theorem is that: after having fixed any bases in the domain and codomain, every linear map can be written of the form $x\mapsto Ax$ for a unique *matrix* $A$ (where we coordinatize the vectors w.r.t the given bases).

Comment: Btw, this particular $f$, geometrically, is an orthogonal projection (to its image, which is a line in the plane), and $b_1,b_2$ is an orthonormal eigenbasis.